# Using hfsql with python

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to an hfsql database using python. I found this syntax on a forum :

```
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={HFSQL};'
                      'Server Name=XXXXX;'
                      'Database=XXXXX;'
                      'UID=XXXXX;'
                      'PWD=XXXX;'
                      "Server Port=XXXX;"
                      )

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT TOP 10 * FROM mytable')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

The issue is that when I execute this code on jupyter notebook, it runs for a few moments then I get an error telling me that the kernel died and it has to restart.

Do you know why I get this error all the time ?

Thank you !

Comment: Which OS are you using? … Windows?  … Linux?

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: Does this help? https://help.windev.com/?3044179

Comment: The thing is that I am currently using a connector to hfsql with Rstudio and everything is working well but with i didn't manage to use it with python. Is there another way to connect to an hfsql database in python ?

Comment: Is Rstudio using an ODBC connection? (Do you have to provide it with a connection string like the one you're trying to use with pyodbc?)

Comment: Yes Rstudio is using an ODBC connection (the package RODBC)